# Low Voltage Marx Generator Switch

Tags: oscillator, opto-isolator, solid-state-relay, tesla-coil

I have a low voltage Marx generator which is connected to a coil inductor, eventually forming an LC oscillator. I want to find a way to switch the circuit on, but because the voltage is low I cannot use spark gaps.

I have studied quite a lot lately and I am thinking of either using a triac driven by an optocoupler, or using a solid state relay. My problem is that I don't think there are any optocouplers that can withstand 5-8 Amperes.

What is your opinion? Is an SSR a better solution?

Comment: Please post a schematic of this "Low voltage Marx generator"

Comment: Your question is a bit vague mate. From what you are saying, your going to build this contraption yourself so its going to be dirty so it would save the hassle to slap a relay on there rated for you max voltage and current. I would edit the question, so we know why you need opto-couples? Isolation?